# Explanation of a Foucault pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames

The equations of motion of a [Foucault pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum) is given by:

$$\ddot{x} = 2\omega \sin\lambda \dot{y} - \frac{g}{L}x$$
$$\ddot{y} = -2\omega \sin\lambda \dot{x} - \frac{g}{L}y$$

where $\omega$ is the rotational frequency of the earth which has a value of $7.27 x 10^-5$,
$\lambda$ is the latitude of where the pendulum is, $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, $L$ is the length of the pendulum's string. What I don't know is what does $x$ and $y$ represent? I have read some derivations of these equations but I really cant figure out what they are trying to say.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55650/2451

Answer (score 1):

The $x$ represents the x-coordinate of the pendulum.

The $y$ represents the y-coordinate of the pendulum.

$x$ and $y$ are perpindicular to each other, but parallel to the Earth's surface.  $z$, not mentioned in these equations is height.

Comment: So it represents the position of the bob?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Might as well ask this, do you have any idea how to simulate a foucault pendulum in matlab?

Comment: @user61835 http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/simulink/examples/modeling-a-foucault-pendulum.html  <- explains how to model it in matlab.